# Limiting zoom/viewable area with Google Earth API

Tags: javascript, zooming, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I know this is not nearly as straightforward as it is with the Maps API v3, but what would be the best way to effectively limit the zoom or viewable area (if the latter is even possible) with the Earth API?  We are trying to prevent people from inadvertently zooming out too far when navigating the small focus area of our map.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but my first attempt would probably be to listen for the viewchanged event, and check the current view to see if it matches your criteria.  If not, you could then flyTo something within your view, and hopefully the effect would be somewhat smooth (but I'm not too sure it would be totally smooth).

See http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#viewchange_event_(and_viewchangebegin,_viewchangeend) for an example of checking for the viewchanged event.